# Is there way to increment values through an equation/function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, sum

In an effort to save time, I'm attempting to increment a value in an equation rather than manually entering it. I've created a script that increases the values, but it only goes through the first one, thus I'm having difficulties looping it. I want to generate several sums based on the increment values, such as when A is 300, sum it up, then sum it up again when A is 310, etc. I'm utilizing an Excel-imported column dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\garyj\OneDrive\Documents\Data\20220204Python\PineMountain.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['RD', 'RG'])


def A():
    if hasattr(A, "num"):
        A.num += 10           # increment if not first call
    else:
        A.num = 200         # initialize on first call
    return A.num

print("A Values:\n")
for i in range(11):
        print(A())
        

def B():
    if hasattr(B, "num"):
        B.num += 0.1           # increment if not first call
    else:
        B.num = 1.4         # initialize on first call
    return B.num

print("B Values:\n")
for i in range(3):
        print(B())
        

def RAD():
    RADAR = (((1/A())*df['RD']**(1/B()))*0.0393701)
    return RADAR 
RADAR = RAD()
print("Radar Rainfall Rate (in):\n")
print (RADAR)

sum2 = RADAR.sum()
print ('Total Rainfall from Radar: ' + str(sum2))
```

I'm looking to loop both A and B but A is more important.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVeRc.png)

Comment: Could you please add an example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll just want

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'RD': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

# Generate the A and B columns based on the zero-based index
df['A'] = (200 + df.index * 10)
df['B'] = (1.4 + df.index * 0.1)
# Generate the RADAR column based on the RD column and the A and B columns
df['RADAR'] = (1 / df["A"] * df['RD'] ** (1 / df["B"])) * 0.0393701

print(df)

sum2 = df.RADAR.sum()
print(f'Total Rainfall from Radar: {sum2}')
```

The output is

```
   RD    A    B     RADAR
0   1  200  1.4  0.000197
1   2  210  1.5  0.000298
2   3  220  1.6  0.000356
3   4  230  1.7  0.000387
4   5  240  1.8  0.000401
5   6  250  1.9  0.000404
6   7  260  2.0  0.000401
Total Rainfall from Radar: 0.002443048238239593
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's guiding me on the right direction. Is there any way to limit the increment to only go up to 400 or so?  I am looking to apply one A value to the whole column, add it up, save it, and repeat A + 10. I've added a sample of the data that I'm using.

Comment: @JalonGary I'm not sure I'm exactly following your requirements. In terms of a dataframe (or Excel sheet), what should things look like? (You could edit that into your question.)